# Почему gtag не отправляет данные в google analytics

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics

Я хочу отправить данные о том на какую страницу заходит пользователь из vue js,
вот таким образом, но это не работает

```
 {
   path: '/test',
   name: 'test',
   component: () => import('./views/comp.vue'),
   beforeEnter: (to,from,next)=>{
   gtag('event', 'zakazat', {'send_to': 'key', 'event_category': 'button'});
   next();
 }
 }
```

Почему? при том что из консоли если повесить лисенеры все улетает

Comment: А должен? У Вас глобально эта функция подключена?

Comment: да глобально, в head